# Is current directly or inversely proportional to potential difference?

Tags: electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance

Ohm's law states that current flowing in a conductor is directly proportional to the potential difference applied across it's ends provided that physical conditions and temperature of the conductor remain constant.
So according to Ohm's law current is directly proportional to potential difference.

Now with the relation $P=VI$( where $P$ stands for Electrical power, $V$ stands for potential difference and $I$ stands for current) it shows that for a power $P$, $I = \frac{P}{V}$ i.e higher the voltage lower is current.

Now with the formula of potential difference i.e. $V_1-V_2=\frac{W}{Q}$,
it shows the relation that increase in charge results in increase in current and decrease in potential difference (provided the work done is constant).

So I am confused whether increase in current results in a reduced potential difference or an increased potential difference, and why.

Comment: The question in the last paragraph is a separate question and should be removed from this question and asked separately

Comment: Ok I will do the needful

Comment: For a given device, it is incorrect to assume that electrical power will remain constant if the voltage across that device changes.

Answer (score 2):

Both $P=IV$ and $V=IR$ are simultaneously satisfied at all times where $V$ is the voltage difference across a resistor of resistance $R$, and $I$ is the current through it, and $P$ is the power it dissipates. If you solve those two equations for $I$ and $V$ you get $V=\sqrt{P R}$ and $I=\sqrt{P/R}$.

As far as whether $I$ is proportional to $V$ or not, the question is unfortunately ambiguous. You need to define what you are keeping fixed and what you are allowing to vary.

If you keep $R$ fixed and vary $P$ then you will find that $I$ is directly proportional to $V$. If you keep $P$ fixed and vary $R$ then they will be inversely proportional. This is not a contradiction, it is two different comparisons.

We can do a contour plot of power as a function of voltage and current. Contour lines are then lines of constant power and show the typical inverse proportional form: [image]

Similarly we can do a contour plot of resistance as a function of voltage and current. Contour lines are then lines of constant resistance and show the typical linear proportionality: [image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no proportionality between potential difference and current unless you want to arbitrarily set some. This is like asking if distance and time are proportional because speed classic formula uses both. Potential difference and current are two orthogonal (ie. unrelated) dimensions, like X and Y in cartesian coordinates..

You may introduce proportionality by setting up constants, such as power. If you decide or observe power to be of a certain value, knowing potential (U) or current (I) will get you the other one. Same if you know the resistance and only U or I.

Also to be clear, proportionality is not just a matter of sign. Saying U and I are proportional would mean they are the same thing, only with a different multiplicative factor.
Nowhere is the ratio between current and voltage set in stone (powers vary, resistances vary, etc.)